# Unable to access BIOS after updating Vista to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios

My laptop has two drive bays, and I want to have a dual boot system.

I have installed a clone of my Windows 8 (it works) and want to 'upgrade' it to 64-bit instead of x86 with the x64 disc that I bought and got posted out. I want to boot off the DVD I have.

However, on this Toshiba Satellite Vista laptop <kbd>F2</kbd> used to provide access to the BIOS, but now it never works and goes straight to Windows 8. (There is a related question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/473215/is-there-something-like-a-bios-in-windows-8) that was closed.)

I have tried all the usual alternatives but just get a long beep when I press any key (<kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd> etc.) So, my question is, *how do I access the BIOS*, now that Windows 8 has hijacked it without telling me beforehand?

Comment: Hold down the F2 key and then power-on the computer.

Comment: See [these](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/open-advanced-startup-options-windows-8.htm) [pages](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/advanced-startup-options-menu-in-windows-8/) for help.

Answer (score 1):

This was somewhat planned by Microsoft. Try going to `PC Settings > General > Advanced Startup` and select "Restart now" to get into the UEFI BIOS where you can tell Windows/the BIOS to boot from a different device.

More info here: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/designing-for-pcs-that-boot-faster-than-ever-before)